# As user can I see my flagged history on a question?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I noticed I flagged the same question 4 times in 2 years for the same reason. I'm consistent with myself even if the admin is not agree with me. I understand this is not efficient for the community. How can I see what I already flagged to avoid to flag it again?

Comment: Answer is there http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history/132040#132040

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed when I flag a question I already flagged there is a little message at the bottom of the flag request popup window. I never noticed it before.

Comment: It's a relatively new feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405 You last flagged your posts before the feature was implemented. It doesn't look at which posts you flagged - it looks at how many of your flags were declined.

Comment: That why I don't see all my flagged questions?

Comment: Ok, but this not an answer to your own question because we still don't know how a user can see the history of all its flags.

Comment: @BoltClock: How does knowing your last fifty flags were bad help avoid re-flagging the same post for the fifth time?

Comment: @Deduplicator: If your *last fifty flags* were declined, you suck at flagging and you should *never flag anything ever again*. Hyperbole aside, you will always have full access to your flagging history regardless of recent outcomes, so you can check which posts you've flagged at any time. The warning is there to remind you about your flags that have been declined - again, regardless of which posts they were raised on.